# Uploading images in djangorestframework

Tags: django-rest-framework

How can I upload images in Django?
If I now want to upload my image I have to first bring the image to the media folder then type the name of the image to include the image in the API but I want to add the images, not in that way I want to upload the image.

Here is My models.py

```
   class Project(models.Model):
       title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
       body = models.TextField(max_length=5000)
       header_image = models.ImageField(default="default.jpg")
       demo = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
       code = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
```

here is my views:

```
@api_view(["POST"])
def addProject(request):
    data = request.data
    project = Project.objects.create(
    title=data["title"],
    body=data["body"],
    header_image=data["header_image"],
    demo=data["demo"],
    code=data["code"],
    )
    serializer = ProjectSerializer(project, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

and here is my serializers:

```
class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
comments = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

class Meta:
    model = Project
    fields = '__all__'

    def get_comments(self, obj):
        comment = obj.comments.all()
        serializer = CommentSerializer(comment, many=True)
        return serializer.data
```

How can I upload my image in the API without manually dragging the folder in the media folder and typing the image file name?

Comment: Why are you putting images in the media folder to begin with. I don't think it's the best strategy.

Comment: I simply wan to upload images to the api.

Comment: The best thing to do is to use a file storage service like Amazon S3 to store files. Also, check out boto3 with django. I use the combination all the time without a hassle.

Comment: @because_im_batman is right. Generally you want a solution where you upload the file somewhere and store the link pointing to that file.  However, if you insist, you can use python file APIs to manipulate the file and store it in the folder you want. Alternatively you can store it in the database as a blob